# is it possible for user to enter values in combobox in vb.net if the drop down doesn't have avaliable values

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and have a window app, I need to have a combobox to show a list of lot numbers for users, but if the user doesn't find the lot number he needs from drop down list, he needs to be able to enter his own number in the text field of the combobox. I remember I've seen this kind of web page before, but the combobox in vb.net is not editable. anyway to do that, Please let me know.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of a ComboBox control added to a WinForms application is to allow the user to edit the text field. If your ComboBox is not editable you need to set the `DropDownStyle` property of the ComboBox to `DropDown`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! the dropdownstyle property is already set to dropdown, but the combobox is not editable, user only able to select not enter. very strange!

Comment: Also, the data in drop down list is pulled from database, is this is the reason that it cannot be edited?